# php - Gravity Form: How can i add a percentage to price in a range of time?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to add a percentage tax to gravity form total only when the user fills the time field input with a value that is range of time that start at 22:00 and end at 6:00. In other words, I have two input field (Hour and Minute) that the user can fill to decide at what hour he want to pickup by a transfer. What i want is if the user decide to be picked up from 22:00 to 6:00 (and fills the hours and minutes field with random hours that is inside this range of time) he will pay 20% tax on price. Here is my function, but is not seems to work. You can help me please?

```
<?php

$form_id = rgget( 'id' );

if ( $form_id == 3 ) :

add_filter( 'gform_field_value_time', 'range_time' );
function range_time( $value ) { 

    if ( $value >= 22 && $value < 6 ) : ?>

    <script>
        gform.addFilter( 'gform_product_total', function(total, formId){
            var tax = 20,
            newtax  = ( total * tax ) / 100 ;
            return total + newtax;
         });
    </script>

    endif;

<?php } ?>

endif; ?>
```

Comment: add_filter must return something ... add_filter is used to modify and input value, maybe you need to add you JS code in the front end and watch the value of the input

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I've yet try to put my js in the front end but it return always the tax incrementation. Iwant, instead, that tha tax is applied only in the range time from 22:00 to 6:00.

Comment: because your JS is missing, it's always adding, you need to add the condition inside the JS